# Callback after posting message to Twitter

Tags: twitter, sharing

I am posting messgae to twiter via link:
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=Hello

I am interested in if it is possible to be redirected to some url after posting message? For example Facebook has "redirect_uri" parameter added to the URL. User is redirected to this URL after the meesage is posted on the wall.

Comment: Here is a working example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305586/after-successful-tweet-execute-the-callback-twitter/47453295#47453295

Answer (score 4):

You can use events binding for Web Intents to redirect to a url after tweeting.

```
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
  js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) { //redirect to your url  } );
});
```

Following links might help :

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events#events

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/671

Comment: "This event will be triggered when the user clicks a Tweet Web Intent." - This means it is triggered before and not after the tweet. A user may cancel before sending the tweet...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent), the tweet web intent does not have a parameter that allows the user to return to your website after the tweet is posted.

Most websites that I've seen present the web intent in a popup instead of sending the user away from their site.