# Twitter share in responsive website

Tags: twitter

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=xxxx" class="tweetShare"><img src="img/twitter-button.png" alt=""></a>
```

I used above code for twitter share in my website. In this method have issue in redirect.

How to fix this issue?

I need solution for mobile website

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you are asking.

Comment: I need redirect website after share a tweet

Comment: To Twitter to tweet, or to another website of your preference after the tweet?

Answer (score 1):

Well as I understand your question It's flexible enough to redirect you URL after tweet Check out below URL same question there:

[Callback after posting message to Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515728/callback-after-posting-message-to-twitter)

For all available options in this approach:
https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

I would recommend here that you should use open in another window approach see below link: 
https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents