# After successful tweet, execute the callback + Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am doing the "share on Twitter" functionality. I have share button and when I click it will open a widget of twitter and showing me the share box. When I will press on Tweet button of widget , it will post my message on my twitter timeline.

now I want to handle a callback, when I tweet successfully, the pop up should not display and my website should redirect next page.

I refereed  [Is there a callback for Twitter's Tweet Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947825/is-there-a-callback-for-twitters-tweet-button) this question but not working as per my requirements.

Twitter providing the events but it will execute on Tweet button which are embedded in our site. My tried with following code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/" data-via="pinceladasdaweb" data-lang="pt" data-text="Pinceladas da Web">Tweetar</a>
```

Js code:

```
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function () {
    alert('Tweeted!');
});
});
```

});

Is there a way to redirect to next page after successful tweet?

Comment: what code you are trying?

Comment: Will you mind sharing what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7  I have added the code, please have look into it.

Comment: check your console for errors and share that;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I have added my latest cod, please let me know how to handle success callback of tween button of twitter widget.

Answer (score 4):

Generally there is no method or intent for a callback from a tweet. I used below hack to make a callback after a successful tweet:

```
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

$(document).on('click','.twitter',function(){

   var tweetUrl = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+window.location.href;
   var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
    var child = window.open(tweetUrl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400,left="+x+",top="+y);
       child.focus();
      var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 1);
      document.domain = 'example.com';     //Replace it with your domain
      function checkChild() {
        if(child.closed){
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
        if(child.window && child.window.closed){   //Code in this condition will execute after successfull post
          //Do your stuff here
          console.log('I am here after a successful tweet.');
          clearInterval(timer);
        }  
      }
});

<a class="twitter"  href="javascript:void(0)">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: I'm testing it on my localhost but it never gets into the // Do your stuff callback and `child.window.closed` is null and returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of null`

Comment: I edited your code and provided a working example. Changed `child.window.closed` to `child.window === null`. This eliminates the TypeError and preserves the intended behavior.

Comment: It will execute each time even if i close tweet popup so I have rejected your suggestion.

Comment: I have added a below check that will remove TypeError:                                                                            if(child.window && child.window.closed){

Comment: Could it be that something changed in the Twitter side that broke this solution? Cause I'm using the exact same code and somehow it's never getting into the "successful tweet" condition.
I'm doing it in localhost, and I'm not sure if this line could cause any troubles: `document.domain = 'localhost';`

Comment: Can anyone give me other solution it's not working .