# How can I run an event when a user tweets a post from my web page?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I need to know when a user tweets my blog's content because I want to register that activity on the database, is there any way to do that? Using a simple button like this one?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Or how can I do it? Maybe using API's callback?

Comment: This looks good, integrated with Twitter's script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947825/is-there-a-callback-for-twitters-tweet-button

Comment: I realized that it works on first action but actually I need to run the event in the second one, once the tweet is already done... I mean, when users click popup's tweet button

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305586/after-successful-tweet-execute-the-callback-twitter/47453295#47453295

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305586/after-successful-tweet-execute-the-callback-twitter/47453295#47453295

Answer (score 0):

At first I thinked about adding an event listener to the anchor, but that wouldn't work, **because Twitter's API converts it to an iframe**.

Reading a bit the [Twitter's JavaScript Widget API Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events) I came up with this:

```
  twttr.ready(
  function(twttr) {
      twttr.events.bind('click', function(event) {
          //Here you can place your code for an AJAX call
          console.log('click on share button')
      });
  });
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grEBvr

Note: it triggers on click, so not when the user actually shared, didn't find an event for `shared`.

Note 2: had to remove the `async` attribute in the `<script>`, was giving issues like "twttr is undefined".

Comment: it seems twitter removed the callback from popup's tweet button action, so maybe it's imposible to know how to generate something when a tweet is actually tweeted :/, i guess that (probably) it has to be related with user's  rewarding by tweet contents